# Sextante in QGIS - downloaded, but does not show up

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante-qgis-plugin

I downloaded Sextante, and I put it into the directory

C:\users[my_user_directory].qgis\python\plugins\sextante-1.0.9\sextant

I re-started the computer, but there is still no sign of Sextante in QGIS, neither in plug-ins manager, nor menu items.

Do I have one directory layer too many in the file path above? Is that why it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of qgis are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since QGIS 2.0.1, Sextante is renamed to `Processing` and part of the core distribution.

No need to download it separately anymore. The one you have will not work with QGIS 2.0.